# How do I combine the Excel formulas for a SUMIF and find number in text string?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs

I have a table in excel which has the date as column header and the rows have Project name, Area, and Resources (example below).
[image: Table example]

As you can see in the example, there are a number of different resources listed for Project 1 in column 01/06/2020.
Normally to add up all resources on a particular date I would use the formula

`=SUMIF(tblPrgmm[Programme],"Resource",tblPrgmm[01/06/2020])`

but for extracting the number of Pn's from the string I would use the formula

```
=MID(G21,FIND("pn",LOWER(G21),1)-1,1)
```

I need to somehow combine the two formulas so that it locates all the resource cells for that date, then extracts the relevant number from the text string.

I have tried

```
=SUMPRODUCT((tblPrgmm[Programme]="Resource"),(MID(tblPrgmm[01/06/2020],FIND("pn",LOWER(tblPrgmm[01/06/2020]),1)-1,1)))
```

and

```
=SUMIF(tblPrgmm[Programme],"Resource",MID(G21,FIND("pn",LOWER(G21),1)-1,1))
```

but I cannot get this to work.
Please help.

Comment: So you just want to add all the numeric characters from the string `1Pn+0PA+1CST+2PSO`?

Comment: No. Each type of resource will have it's own formula. I will have one formula that will add all of the pn's for a given date and one for PA's etc.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to find a project before searching for 'Resource'. You may use the following formula:

```
{=MID(INDEX(Table1[#All],MATCH(G1,Table1[Programme],0)+3,MATCH(TEXT(G2, "dd.MM.yyyy"),Table1[#Headers],0)),FIND("pn",LOWER(INDEX(Table1[#All],MATCH(G1,Table1[Programme],0)+3,MATCH(TEXT(G2, "dd.MM.yyyy"),Table1[#Headers],0))),1)-1,1)}
```

[image]

Format date in formula as you need.

**Edit**

OK, here will be an option with the summing of all project resources on a single date:

```
{=SUM(IF((G1=Table1[Programme])*(TEXT(G2,"dd.MM.yyyy")=Table1[#Headers]),VALUE(MID(Table1,SEARCH(G3,Table1,1)-1,1)),0))}
```

[image]

Comment: I was wanting to add up all pn's across all projects for a particular date not just one project. Hopefully in a particular way so that if a new project gets added to the bottom of the table it will still add that on too without changing the formula.